# Unity5 I lost my codes inside .cs file. C# files still exist, but codes gone

Tags: metafile, unity-game-engine

Unity 5.1.2f1 (64-bit) version.(windows 8.1) I closed Unity. After a while ago I opened Unity and I had some errors in Console.Then I clicked the error and I realized that I lost my code in some of my C# files.Then I checked folders of my scripts and I checked date modified section of my C# files.

Here is image of my problem.

http://www.imagesturk.net/images/2015/08/19/Capture662cb.md.png

as you can see, some of file's modified date is in 7th month and other's modified date is in 8th date. Problem is I just saved those file's (7th month) just couple of days.

I had this problem before as well. That time only few changes lost and I re-code those files, but not I lost hundreds lines of codes, so I can't re-code all same. **Is there any way to recover those codes?**

Comment: You should learn how to use revision control software, even for personal projects. Revision control helps to recover from disasters like the one you describe.  I personally recommend Mercurial + TortoiseHg, but there are many others out there.

Comment: Try to look through local history in Unity. You should be able to restore it to some previous state.